# Obtain the respective rankings of an object in many variables

Tags: r, rstudio

This a simplified display of my data:

[image]

I am interested in how Germany rankings on each of the variables, population, area, Literacy rate_male, etc.

How can I do it?

Comment: Please provide your data as text so that we can copy & paste to use it. You can use `dput()` to do that.

Comment: It would be better if you give a reproducible example. Please read [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/4996248)

Comment: *"I am interested in how Germany rankings on each of the variables, population, area, Literacy rate_male, etc."* I don't understand what that means. Do you want to rank values in `Population`, `Area`, etc. and then determine the rank of `location_name = Germany`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a dataframe with one variable the name of a country and the others numeric. To get an easily reproducible example with a similar structure: start with the built-in dataframe `mtcars` (evaluate `?mtcars` for details) and then run the following two commands:

```
mtcars$make <- row.names(mtcars)
row.names(mtcars) <- NULL
```

Say you wanted to get the ranks of `Datsun 710` (the third row of the dataframe). Then you could use:

```
ranks <- apply(mtcars[,names(mtcars) != "make"],2,function(v) rank(v)[which(mtcars$make == "Datsun 710")])
```

Resulting variable looks like:

```
> ranks
 mpg  cyl disp   hp drat   wt qsec   vs   am gear carb 
24.5  6.0  6.0  7.0 20.0  7.0 23.0 25.5 26.0 21.5  4.0
```

In your case, something along the lines of

```
ranks <- apply(df[,names(df) != "location_name"],2,function(v) rank(v)[which(df$location_name == "Germany")])
```

should work.